# Get connection string in .NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to get **connection string** dynamically from **appsettings.json** file. I see that I can do that via **Configuration** property of **startup** class. I've marked Configuration field as static field and access it across the app.

I'm wondering if there is a **better** way to get connection string value from **.NET Core** app.

Comment: You can inject the `Configuration` object through the dependency injection service in ASP.NET Core - [Example here](https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-configuration-greeting/#making-use-of-asp-net-core-dependency-injection)

Comment: How can I inject Configuration object into class that has only parameterless constructor? Or even how can I inject db context into class that has only parameterless constructor?

Comment: At least in ASP.NET core the recommended approach is using the options pattern considering SoC and and ISP principles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects 

These principles should be considered for a .NET Core solution, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check my blog article on ASP.NET Core Configuration [here](https://joonasw.net/view/asp-net-core-1-configuration-deep-dive).

In it I also go through Dependency Injection of configuration options.

Quote:

> There are a couple ways to get settings. One way would be to use the
>   Configuration object in Startup.cs.
>
> You can make the configuration available in your app globally through
>   Dependency Injection by doing this in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:
>
> services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

Comment: How can I inject Configuration object into class that has only parameterless constructor? Or even how can I inject db context into class that has only parameterless constructor?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm also a beginner on ASP.NET Core apps, didn't knew we could do something like this. That's great!

Comment: @A.Gladkiy ASP.NET Core DI with the default IoC container uses only constructor injection. You cannot inject services into a class in a different way. You should look if someone else has asked this question before, and if not, ask a new a question about this.

Comment: Wish the answer showed you how to do it instead of pointing to other web sites. Just a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a thread-safe `Singleton` of your `IConfiguration` variable declared in the `Startup.cs` file.

```
private static object syncRoot = new object();
private static IConfiguration configuration;
public static IConfiguration Configuration
{
    get
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            return configuration;
    }
}

public Startup()
{
    configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().Build(); // add more fields
}
```

Comment: I tried this in a console app but there is no Startup.cs, so I tried to add one, but it's not calling the constructor. How did you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
    public IConfiguration Configuration;
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewerController(IHostingEnvironment hostEnvironment, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        Configuration = config;
    }
```

and in class that you want connection string

```
 var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SQLCashConnection");
```